# Is there a way to track events from iframe on ios?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, safari, analytics, google-tag-manager

The GA is not working on ios for iframe.
I am loading our plugin page from different domain on a client's website using iframe.
I have added cookie flag on GTM and pasted GTM code only plugin php page, the events are firing on windows and android whenever I visit the website. I am using UA version of GA.
If I go to the plugin page directly it works on ios.
But it doesn't work on ios when I go to the website.
Any idea?

Comment: you have to debug it properly before asking:  
1. Is it the same origin iframe? 
2. Is it safari-only? It's unlikely to depend on the OS.
3. How do you check if an event is sent?
4. Do you see this reflected in GA data?

Comment: It is cross origin iframe. It is working on UA after adding cookie storage none. But it is not working on GA4 only for safari, there is no option to set cookie storage for GA4 on GTM.
Any workaround idea?